# How to configure custom Listview along with custom editable child ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, expandablelistview, flutter-web

I've a functionality to implement, where I need to configure a custom listview of each widget containing a TextField and a button. And the child widget contains the listview of each widget containing a TextField to enter the new course.

[image: Overview]

Following is the functionality.

1. Step 1 is static field to enter the course.
2. After entering the course, clicking on the add button in the course field would add a ListView of dynamic widget (parent listview) of any topic.
3. Once the topic widget loads, clicking on the right add button needs to append a child listview of another dynamic widget to the parent (child listview) of the subtopics.
4. So, in the above picture, 2, 4 are the parent listviews and 3, 5 needs to be child listviews

Following is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: NewCourse()));
}

class NewCourse extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewCourseState createState() => _NewCourseState();
}

class _NewCourseState extends State<NewCourse> {
  bool isTagSelected = false;
  bool isTopicCreationEnabled = false;

  List<NewTopic> newTopicList = [];

  addNewTopic() {
    newTopicList.add(new NewTopic());
    setState(() {});
  }

  enableTopicCreation(String txtTopicName) {
    setState(() {
      if (txtTopicName.length > 0) {
        isTopicCreationEnabled = true;
      } else {
        isTopicCreationEnabled = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _createNewTopic;

    if (isTopicCreationEnabled) {
      _createNewTopic = () {
        addNewTopic();
      };
    } else {
      _createNewTopic = null;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        title: Text('ALL COURSES'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  "NEW COURSE",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'CodeFont',
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                  blurRadius: 20.0,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 9,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            enableTopicCreation(text);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "Course Name",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: _createNewTopic,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add_box,
                            color: isTopicCreationEnabled
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.blueGrey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Expanded(
              child: getAllTopicsListView(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getAllTopicsListView() {
    ListView topicList = new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: newTopicList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new NewTopic(),
          );
        });
    return topicList;
  }
}

class NewTopic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTopicState createState() => _NewTopicState();
}

class _NewTopicState extends State<NewTopic> {
  bool isSubTopicCreationEnabled = false;

  List<NewSubTopic> newSubTopicList = [];

  addNewSubTopic() {
    setState(() {
      newSubTopicList.add(new NewSubTopic());
    });
  }

  enableSubTopicCreation(String txtTopicName) {
    setState(
      () {
        if (txtTopicName.length > 0) {
          isSubTopicCreationEnabled = true;
        } else {
          isSubTopicCreationEnabled = false;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _createNewSubTopic;

    if (isSubTopicCreationEnabled) {
      _createNewSubTopic = () {
        addNewSubTopic();
      };
    } else {
      _createNewSubTopic = null;
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 50),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey[400],
                blurRadius: 20.0,
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 9,
                      child: Container(
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            enableSubTopicCreation(text);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "Enter the topic",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: _createNewSubTopic,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add_box,
                            color: isSubTopicCreationEnabled
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.blueGrey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Expanded(
                        //child: Text("Hi There!"),
                        child: getAllSubTopicsListView(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getAllSubTopicsListView() {
    ListView subTopicList = new ListView.builder(
       itemCount: newSubTopicList.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return new ListTile(
           title: new NewSubTopic(),
         );
       },
     );
     return subTopicList;
  }
}

class NewSubTopic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewSubTopicState createState() => _NewSubTopicState();
}

class _NewSubTopicState extends State<NewSubTopic> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey[400],
                blurRadius: 20.0,
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Enter the sub topic",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the issue

[image: Error]

```
Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:545:12
child.hasSize
is not true
```

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to shrinkwrap the ListViews:

```
        ListView topicList = new ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: newTopicList.length,
        //...
        ListView subTopicList = new ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: newSubTopicList.length,
```

> A ListView is basically a CustomScrollView with a single SliverList in
> its CustomScrollView.slivers property.

> If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will expand to the maximum allowed size in the scrollDirection. If the scroll view has unbounded constraints in the scrollDirection, then shrinkWrap must be true.

You can learn more about [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [shrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) in the [official documentaion](https://api.flutter.dev/index.html).